# How to create a Popover view with Applescript?

Tags: applescript-objc

I'd like to know how to display a message by clicking a popover style button, could anyone here guide me to do this?
For example, clicking a button opens a Popover view informing me of my IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An NSPopover is just a view that you can show at some location in another view, so you can show it from the button's action handler.

For an example, create whatever you are wanting to put in the popover, such as an **NSTextField**, then create an **NSViewController** large enough to contain it.  Next, create the **NSPopover**, set its `contentViewController` to the view controller, and show it via its `showRelativeToRect:ofView:preferredEdge:` at the desired location:

```
use framework "Cocoa"

property theWindow : missing value -- the main window

on run -- run on main thread if using the Script Editor
    if current application's NSThread's isMainThread() as boolean then
        doStuff()
    else
        my performSelectorOnMainThread:"doStuff" withObject:(missing value) waitUntilDone:true
    end if
end run

to doStuff() -- make a window to put the example stuff in
    set theWindow to current application's NSWindow's alloc's initWithContentRect:{{200, 400}, {200, 100}} styleMask:7 backing:(current application's NSBackingStoreBuffered) defer:true
    theWindow's contentView's addSubview:(my makeButtonWithTitle:"Button" atLocation:{60, 40})
    theWindow's makeKeyAndOrderFront:me
end doStuff

to makeButtonWithTitle:title atLocation:location -- make a button at {x, y}
    tell (current application's NSButton's buttonWithTitle:title target:me action:"buttonAction:") -- 10.12 Sierra and later
        its setFrameOrigin:location
        its sizeToFit() -- fit to the title
        its setRefusesFirstResponder:true -- no highlight
        return it
    end tell
end makeButtonWithTitle:atLocation:

on buttonAction:sender -- do something when the button is clicked
    set title to sender's title
    set testString to "This is some popover text
located at " & quoted form of (title as text) & "." -- whatever
    set {{x, y}, {width, height}} to (sender's frame()) as list -- for adjusting the location of the pointer
    set x to x + (width div 2) -- center horizontally
    set y to y + (height div 2) -- center vertically
    my showPopoverWithMessage:testString atPoint:{x, y} inView:(sender's |window|'s contentView()) -- use the window the button is in for the view
end buttonAction:

to showPopoverWithMessage:theMessage atPoint:thePoint inView:theView -- build and show the popover
    set textField to makeTextField() -- make a text field
    textField's setStringValue:theMessage -- put something in it
    textField's sizeToFit() -- resize the text field to fit the string
    set {width, height} to second item of (textField's frame as list) -- to size the view to the text field
    set popoverView to current application's NSView's alloc's initWithFrame:{{0, 0}, {width + 15, height + 15}} -- make a view to hold everything
    popoverView's addSubview:textField -- put the text field in it
    set popoverViewController to current application's NSViewController's alloc's init -- make a controller for the popover view
    popoverViewController's setView:popoverView -- set the view to it

    tell current application's NSPopover's alloc's init() -- make the popover
        its setContentViewController:popoverViewController
        its setBehavior:(current application's NSPopoverBehaviorTransient)
        its showRelativeToRect:{thePoint, {1, 1}} ofView:theView preferredEdge:(current application's NSMaxYEdge) -- and show it
    end tell
end showPopoverWithMessage:atPoint:inView:

to makeTextField() -- make a text field for the popover
    tell (current application's NSTextField's alloc's initWithFrame:{{10, 10}, {100, 100}})
        its setBordered:false
        its setDrawsBackground:false -- label
        its setRefusesFirstResponder:true -- no highlight
        its setAlignment:(current application's NSTextAlignmentCenter) -- or whatever
        its setFont:(current application's NSFont's fontWithName:"Noteworthy Bold" |size|:42)
        its setTextColor:(current application's NSColor's redColor)
        return it
    end tell
end makeTextField
```